# Converting a ground-referenced positive/negative dc voltage to positive voltage

Tags: voltage, conversion

[image]

I'm trying to create a circuit that converts positive or negative dc voltage into a positive voltage at the output. I can't use the conventional full bridge rectifer because my DC sources are not floating - they are grounded. Furthermore, I am unable to use a transformer to "float" my input dc voltage because it is dc. I'm currently looking into optoisolators or other galvanic isolators that may allow me use the full bridge rectifier.

[image]

Any ideas or other architectures to solve this problem are very welcome.

Comment: Why do you think a rectifier requires its input to be floating? Do the two ground symbols in your diagram not indicate the same node?

Comment: 1. The full bridge rectifier takes an AC input. 
2. Yes, the two ground symbols indicate the same node.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the circuit from a "universal input" switchmode AC adapter with 5V output. The input is isolated from the output so the internal bridge rectifier will work fine.

200VDC is about equivalent to about 140VAC RMS. A typical adapter will work down to about 90 or 100VAC so well under 150VDC.

For example, this circuit using a chip from [Power Integrations](https://ac-dc.power.com/sites/default/files/product-docs/tinyswitch-4_family_datasheet.pdf):

[image]

You didn't mention how much current you need- this circuit is good for 4A (20W). Where it says 90-295 VAC, you can apply about 130VDC to 400VDC with either polarity.

The ratings of all the relevant parts should be checked to make sure they are valid for continuous DC.

Comment: On the 5V output, I need no more than ~100mA

Comment: You can use a smaller chip then- check out the other offerings from this maker, or other similar ones, for reference designs.

Comment: I've spent some time looking at the datasheet/block/application diagrams for the TNY290PG and some others from Power Integrations. While this switch will work very well with a purely positive DC supply, it is not very clear to me how it will work with a purely negative DC.

Comment: @Chuck It's isolated so only the polarity of one input lead relative to the other matters from the pov of powering the circuit. Or leave the bridge in there and you can connect it either way 'round.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a transformer with DC if you switch it.  Below is a simplified schematic of how that might be done.  Essentially it is what your second image shows, with isolation (just using a transformer), and then rectification and regulation.  The trick is adding a controller and switch that will work from either polarity source.  You might need another rectifier on the high voltage side to power the switching logic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLlz8M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: (I like the upside down earth for output! :-)

Comment: Right, I prefer to use a bar.  Actually I used an upside-down signal for ground (according to the CircuitLab editor).

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution. I was able to simulate it in LTSpice using a voltage-controlled switch in LTSpice. Now on to finding a single discrete solution that oscillates in that manner.

Comment: Thanks @Chuck, but keep in mind that this simplified and missing suitable feedback.  Sphero's circuit looks more elaborate but you may still need to incorporate some of those features.  You have an advantage that you have a fixed input voltage, so you might get a way with a fixed switching frequency and duty, but you will need to see how good your load regulation is, i.e. do you get stable voltage under the full output current range.

Comment: Yes, I studied Sphero's circuit. It is same idea as this really one really. I'll consider using a SIDAC or a switch with similar V/I characteristics for SW2.